# Storing a ListClass as a ListArray on another Class

Tags: c#, json, wpf, list, class

Not sure if I'm wording the title correctly but here is the situation.

So I'm building a WPF application with visual studios in c#, I have 2 windows the main window and a second window which pops up on button click.

The second window is a form to fill out before saving changes it will basically be used to store some version/update data when changing files in the app.

I have a class called EmailVersionHistory

```
namespace EmailEditor.Model
{
    public class EmailVersionHistory
    {
        public string EmailVersionKey { get; set; }
        public List<EmailVersionData> EmailVersionData { get; set; }
    }
}
```

A second class for the email version data list

```
namespace EmailEditor.Model
{
    public class EmailVersionData
    {
        public string VersionData { get; set; }
        public string UserData { get; set; }
        public string NotesData { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastUpdatedData { get; set; }
    }
}
```

So after filling out the pop up window form and hitting the submit button it should essentially store the information from the text input fields and then serialise and put to a s3 bucket this is the current function code.

```
private void Submit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    IAmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client();
    GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest();
    request.BucketName = "bucket-name";
    request.Key = "email-version-config.json";

    GetObjectResponse response = s3Client.GetObject(request);
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(response.ResponseStream))
    {
        string json = r.ReadToEnd();
        emailHistory = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<EmailVersionHistory>>(json);
    }

    // this is essentially where i get stuck
    List<EmailVersionData.Add(new EmailVersionData() { VersionData = VersionText.Text, UserData = UserText.Text, NotesData = NotesText.Text });
    // this is essentially where i get stuck

    var EmailHistoryJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(emailHistory, Formatting.Indented);

    PutObjectRequest application = new PutObjectRequest();
    application.BucketName = "bucket-name";
    application.Key = "email-version-config.json";
    application.ContentType = "application/json";
    application.ContentBody = EmailHistoryJson;
    s3Client.PutObject(application);
}
```

The closest I got was overwriting the `email-version-config.json` every time I save but I want to store each save data as a new List item so it will work a little bit like a log

```
[
  {
    "EmailVersionKey": "76-83yhhju3298",
    "EmailVersionData": [
      {
        "VersionData": "1.0.1",
        "UserData": "Mark",
        "NotesData": "Changes Made",
        "LastUpdatedData": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
      },
      {
      \\The next save should end up here
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Update 1**

Having made some progress with the help of responses to the original question this is where I am at.

Current Code

```
        var newEmailVersionData = (new EmailVersionData() { VersionData = VersionText.Text, UserData = UserText.Text, NotesData = NotesText.Text });
        var newEmailVersionHistory = (new EmailsVersionHistory() { EmailVersionKey = EmailID });


        var emailHistory = emailHistories.FirstOrDefault(key => key.EmailVersionKey == emailID);

        if (emailHistory.EmailVersionData == null)
        {
            emailHistories.Add(newEmailVersionHistory);
            newEmailVersionHistory.EmailVersionData.Add(newEmailVersionData);
        }
        else
        {
            emailHistory.EmailVersionData.Add(newEmailVersionData);   
        }

        var EmailHistoryJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(emailHistories, Formatting.Indented);
```

The aim is to find an object in the list and add the new version data to it but should the object not exist create the object and then add the new data to it.

The outputted JSON should resemble this.

`[
  {
    "EmailVersionKey": "40-u74hdta58jmf",
    "EmailVersionData": [
      {
        "VersionData": "1.0.0",
        "UserData": "Tam",
        "NotesData": "New Stuff",
        "LastUpdatedData": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
      },
      {
        "VersionData": "1.0.0",
        "UserData": "Mark",
        "NotesData": "More Changes",
        "LastUpdatedData": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
    }
    ]
  },
  {
    "EmailVersionKey": "29-u74hdta58jmf",
    "EmailVersionData": [
      {
       "VersionData": "1.0.0",
       "UserData": "Tam",
       "NotesData": "New Stuff",
       "LastUpdatedData": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
      },
      {
       "VersionData": "1.0.0",
       "UserData": "Mark",
       "NotesData": "More Changes",
       "LastUpdatedData": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
      }
    ]
  }
]`

I understand this is a bit of a long winded explanation so I really appreciated any help I can get and would like to say thanks in advance.

Comment: "this is essentially where i get stuck" -- what stuck you?

Comment: the code that should go there i'm not sure how or what to write to achieve the outcome i desire sorry should probably have explained that lol

Answer (score 0):

Okay I finally figured out what I was doing wrong the problem came down to a lack of understanding how List actually works I was setting the data to newEmailVersionData and then trying to add it to a List that was null/did not exist.

Apologies and Thanks go to the guy who has now removed his answer as it was correct I just didn't understand.

Now for the solution

```
        var emailHistory = emailHistories.FirstOrDefault(key => key.EmailVersionKey == emailID);

        if (emailHistory != null)
        {
            emailHistory.EmailVersionData.Add(newEmailVersionData);
        }
        else
        {
            List<EmailVersionData> list = new List<EmailVersionData>();
            EmailsVersionHistory item = new EmailsVersionHistory() { EmailVersionKey = emailID, EmailVersionData = list };
            list.Add(newEmailVersionData);

            emailHistories.Add(item);
        }
```

All I had to do was create a new List assign that list to the EmailVersionData Value on the EmailVersionHistory Object.

Next add the new data to List and finally add the entire new item to the list of histories.